# Find out the last page the user was on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

Is it possible for me to find out what the last route/page a user was on in one of my controllers? For example, if the user was on /home, then moved to /contact, is there was way for me to find out he was at /home within my controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.referer` will give you the url which issued the request. If you need more informations like the path, you can use [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) and write in your controller something like:

```
last_page_path = URI(request.referer).path
```